# sqlite3 error UNIQUE constraint failed: tablename.id

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I got this sqlite3 code to work perfectly when it was in the main body of the program, and I thought that was that, but then I wrote more code so this would execute once a month (on the first day of the month) and that code works fine, but now when the table entries occur it gives an `sqlite3 error UNIQUE constraint failed: currentMonthStocks.id` I did move the code from the main body into the function at the time I write the monthly call at the bottom, I'm not sure if that is the reason this broke.

I have searched for half a day on this and went over unique keys and so much more, but it appears the problem is that the table name is throwing up a UNIQUE constraint error, which is very strange because the table exists, and there is only 1 table with that name. All of the other code should work fine. I tried to change INSERT INTO to INSERT or IGNORE INTO and the for loop ran, but nothing was inserted. I double checked and the table is empty.

```
def get_symbols_at_month_start() -> None:
"""Function inserts a list of symbols to trade every month into the currentMonthStocks table in database.db.
This is called once at the start of the month, deletes the current symbols and adds the new ones.
:return: None."""

print('running get symbols function')
# curl for marketsmith stocks:
url = "https://marketsmith.investors.com/mstool/api/tool/list-table"

payload = "{...}"
headers = {...}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
symbols = response.json()['content']['allInstrumentRows']
this_months_symbols = []
for symbol in symbols:
    this_months_symbols.append(symbol['Symbol'])

# DATABASE
try:
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    print("Database Connected")

    # c.execute("""CREATE TABLE currentMonthStocks (
    #             id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    #             symbol TEXT,
    #             month INT)""")
    # print("DB created successfully")

    time_now = datetime.datetime.now()  # get current time for the int conversion below
    this_month_int = time_now.month  # get the current month and set it to an int
    db_row_id = 1  # set the first row number

    for i in range(len(this_months_symbols)):
        c.execute("""INSERT INTO currentMonthStocks
                   (id, symbol, month)
                   VALUES (?, ?, ?)""", (db_row_id, this_months_symbols[i], this_month_int))
        db_row_id += 1
        print("one more entry")
    print("symbols successfully populated into db")

    conn.commit()  # commits the current transaction.
    # c.close()  # closes the connection to the db.

except sqlite3.Error as e:
    print("sqlite3 error", e)

finally:
    if conn:
        conn.close()
        print("Database Closed")

# set the timing of the get_symbols_at_month_start() code
today = datetime.datetime.now()
nextMonth = (today.replace(day=1) + datetime.timedelta(days=32)).replace(day=1)  # get first day of next month
diffMins = ((nextMonth - today).total_seconds()) / 60.0  # get difference in minutes

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
# scheduler.add_job(func=get_symbols_at_month_start, trigger='interval', minutes=diffMins)
scheduler.add_job(func=get_symbols_at_month_start, trigger='interval', seconds=8)
scheduler.start()
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: The complaint is not about the table name.  Your table definition has `id` being a primary key.  That means it cannot be duplicated.  Your code always starts adding with `id=1`.  If `id` 1 already exists, that's a UNIQUE constraint failure.  Do you mean to delete all the rows before starting?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't property format the error, but that is actually the entire error message, just one simple line: "sqlite3 error UNIQUE constraint failed: currentMonthStocks.id"

Comment: Right now the table is completely empty, so I don't know how to delete rows that aren't there. But its a good idea, how would write a statement to delete all, or delete rows, or reset to empty?

Comment: Tim Roberts, that was helpful, I removed the id from the insert statement it worked... sort of. The code runs and doesn't throw an error, but it is still not populating the DB with entries. Between the print statements, and this definitely running correctly before moving the code into the function, i'm still pretty puzzled, but thank you for the tip on leaving out the ID column because it will autoincrement.

Comment: for i in range(len(this_months_symbols)):
            c.execute("""INSERT INTO currentMonthStocks
                       (symbol, month)
                       VALUES (?, ?)""", (this_months_symbols[i], this_month_int))

Comment: ok I think this is actually working just fine now that i posted the above comment, the db browser wasn't updating correctly and after i restarted the whole thing it is showing like 6,000 entries (even though the list is 300 long) so I guess all the statements were working. I will get this 100% correct tonight and post a follow up with the working code. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer was mentioned above, I needed to delete all the rows before entering new rows. This issue was exponentially worse than it needed to because DB Browser for SQLite, the app I use to view entries, had an internal error of some sorts, I had to restart my computer and then it turned out I had basically written the code correctly. This ended up being the correct working code:

```
        if c.execute("""SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM currentMonthStocks WHERE id=1 LIMIT 2);"""):
        # for i in range(len(this_months_symbols)):
        c.execute("""DELETE FROM currentMonthStocks""")
        print("delete all rows successful")

    time_now = datetime.datetime.now()  # get current time for the int conversion below
    this_month_int = time_now.month  # get the current month and set it to an int
    db_row_id = 1  # set the first row number

    for i in range(len(this_months_symbols)):
        c.execute("""INSERT INTO currentMonthStocks
                   (id, symbol, month)
                   VALUES (?, ?, ?)""", (db_row_id, this_months_symbols[i], this_month_int))
        db_row_id += 1
        print("one more entry")
    print("symbols successfully populated into db")
```